# Render components from an array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an array of object, containing another array of object like this :

```
[{label: "Commons",
  path: "commons",
  component: Commons,
  subroutes: [
  {
    label: "Commons doc",
    path: "commons/doc",
    component: CommonsDoc,
  }]
 }]
```

Then I pass it as a prop to a component, and map the prop to render in React the first level component "Commons" with this in another bloc :

```
<StyledRouter>
    {routes.map((route, index) => (
        <route.component path={route.path} key={index} />
    ))}
</StyledRouter>
```

I'm using Reach Router for React, and now I'm trying to render the second level component at subroutes, using a second map function right under the first `<route.component path={route.path} key={index} />`

But I can't get it work like this `{route.subroutes.map(...)}` to render the `CommonsDoc` component in my second array of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help you:

```
const composeRoutes = (routes) => {
    allRoutes = routes.map((route, index) => {
        if (route.subroutes.length > 0) {
            let withSubRoutes = [];
            withSubRoutes = composeRoutes(route.subroutes);
            withSubRoutes.append(<route.component path={route.path} key={index} />);
            return withSubRoutes;
        }
        return <route.component path={route.path} key={index} />;
    })
    return _.flatten(allRoutes);
};
<StyledRouter>
    {composeRoutes(routes)}
</StyledRouter>
```

Comment: Awesome ! To anyone having a similar problem, it worked with some modifications : since i'm not using Lodash `_.flatten(allRoutes);` became `allRoutes.flat()` and and error was telling me that `.append` is not a function so it became `.push`

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question right, you should map it like that:

`routes.map(route => route.subroutes).map(subroute => 'do whatever you want with each subroute')`

Comment: No, I don't want to access to subroutes directly ... I need to render components at "first level" from my array, then access to second level (subroutes) to render components from there

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic tag name in JSX you need to  assign the name value to a capitalized variable

```
<StyledRouter>
   {routes.map((route, index) => {
     const Route = route.component;
     return (<Route path={route.path} key={index} />)
   })}
</StyledRouter>
```

and you should do the same thing for subroutes

Comment: If I'm correct, this doesn't really fix the issue that I have ? It's just another way of writing it
I can already render in the first map, the component of my first array of object